# Invalid src prop on `next/image`, hostname "lh3.googleusercontent.com" is not configured under images in your `next.config.js`

Tags: javascript, next.js13, i18next, nextjs-image, next-i18next

how can configure next.config.js to allow image from internet to be shown in our web page in next js version 13.*.

I have tried these code but again shows this error;
Error: Invalid src prop (https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/ACg8ocKmJC1nmylcAXR0-pyi5Zh7sQMAbhLNAiY1KwgG2U6N=s96-c) on `next/image`, hostname "lh3.googleusercontent.com" is not configured under images in your `next.config.js`

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  experimental: {
    appDir: true,
    experiments: {
      topLevelAwait: true,
    },
    serverComponentsExternalPackages: ["mongoose"],
  },
  images: {
    formats: ['image/avif', 'image/webp'],
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: 'https',
        hostname: 'lh3.googleusercontent.com',
        port: '',
        pathname: '/**/**',
      },
    ],
  },
  webpack(config) {
    return config;
  },
  i18n: {
    locales: ["en", "fa"],
    defaultLocale: "en",
    localeDetection: false,
  },
};

const withNextIntl = require("next-intl/plugin")("./i18n.js");

module.exports = withNextIntl({
  nextConfig,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{
        protocol: "https",
        hostname: "lh3.googleusercontent.com",
        port: "",
        pathname: '/*/**',
      },
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35330604)